# Optimize python loop for large list with duplicates

Tags: python

I have a working python code which works, but for large liste (more 100 000) the code is very slow and I need to optimize it.

My list add some duplicate value and I want to group those duplicates in the same input (with quantity update for example).

Ex source list (first entry is the ID of the transaction):

```
id,quantity
1,10 <--
1,20 <--
2,25
3,30
```

and I want:

```
id,quantity
1,30 <--
2,25
3,30
```

Currently the code is based on a for loop, haversine is a function previously declare (in order to calculate distance, not important for this inquery)

```
years = ['2018','2017','2016','2015','2014']

for year in years:
    print(year)
    try:
        with open('/home/' + year + '/' + cod + '.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            lines = [x for x in data]
            for row in lines[::-1]:
                try:
                    x=float(row['latitude'])
                    y=float(row['longitude'])
                    if(math.isnan(x) == False and math.isnan(y) == False):
                        haversine2 = round((haversine(lon1, lat1, float(row['longitude']), float(row['latitude'])))*1000)
                        z=float(haversine2)
                        if(math.isnan(z) == False):
                            if not liste:
                                liste.append([haversine2,row['latitude'],row['longitude'],quantity])

                            else:
                                for idx,sublist in enumerate(liste):
                                    if sublist[2] == id_mut:
                                      liste[idx][3] = sum(filter(None, [liste[idx][3],quantity]))
                                      doublon = 'ok'
                                      break
                                    else:
                                        doublon = 'nok'
                                if doublon != 'ok':
                                  liste.append([haversine2,row['latitude'],row['longitude',quantity]])
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error => : ", str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error => : ", str(e))
```

Update:

Finally @Chris gave me a nice input with the df.groupby pandas function which help me to optimize by 53x the time!

Comment: Is the input sorted by id?

Comment: Any reason not using `pandas`? It looks like a one-liner job for `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`

Comment: @schwobaseggl  no after I sort the result list by the distance calculate by my haversine function

Comment: @Chris I try to not use panda but it's maybe a bad idea to not use panda...

Comment: You can use "for row in reversed(lines):" instead of "for row in lines[::-1]:"  It gives you a reverse iterator instead of building a reversed list.

Comment: @kantal good point!

Answer (score 0):

`collections.defaultdict` might help you here.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)

with open(filename) as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in data:                                   #Iterate each row
        result[row["id"]] += int(row["quantity"])      #groupby and increment. 
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'1': 30, '3': 30, '2': 25})
```